# Run remotely an executable on a virtual machine with Powershell

Tags: powershell, executable, virtual

The setup involves a physical computer (Windows 10), a virtual machine (Windows 10) and an internal server.

From the physical computer, I want to run an executable on the remote virtual machine. The executable (MyProgram.exe) is already on the remote virtual machine. The cmdlet I use is:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName Krypton -ScriptBlock {& "c:\users\qaauto\desktop\PrepareAssemblies"} -Credential ibwave\qaauto
```

I anonymized the cmdlet but I saw that the .EXE ran on the remote VM. But it crashed with an exception when it tries to read a file which is on our server Vader. The exception is:

System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'I:\official\QA\tests\Test parameters - Machine98.xml'.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.File.InternalCopy(String sourceFileName, String destFileName, Boolean overwrite, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.File.Copy(String sourceFileName, String destFileName, Boolean overwrite)
   at PrepareAssemblies.Program.Main(String[] args)

At the command prompt of Powershell, there is no error message. And the prompt becomes accessible after the cmdlet, so it does not hang.

I am sure the service WS-Management is running and is correctly configured on the remote virtual machine because this cmdlet works:

```
enter-pssession -computername Machine98 -credential <domain_name>\<username>
```

The username I use is administrator on the VM but I *guess* that the .EXE does not run as admin when I launch it remotely.

Can you help me find what is wrong with my solution or propose another way of achieving things?

Many thanks!

Comment: There may be more details of the exception in the remote server's event log. Getting this information (and adding to the question!) will make diagnosing the problem much easier.

Comment: First check : is the file which cannot be found present under the correct path on the target machine? If so, does the useraccount which is used to run the script access to that destination? Keep in mind that a mapped network drive (like the I in your error message) might not be mapped under the account running the script. As a tip : NEVER use network drives in scripts, use the UNC path, preferably with the fqdn name instead of a netbios name

Comment: @bluff: The .EXE executes correctly when I launch it manually from the virtual machine so it eliminates all your hypothesis.